# Upgradability Proxy ADMIN_SLOT assembly sstore does not update

Tags: solidity, truffle, assembly

I'm currently playing around with Proxy Upgradability, and noticed the use of assembly in terms of the new upgraded contract and the slot assigned.  Real implementation can be seen [here](https://github.com/zeppelinos/zos/blob/master/packages/lib/contracts/upgradeability/BaseAdminUpgradeabilityProxy.sol).

I have broken this implementation down to understand what is happening:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Base {

bytes32 internal constant IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT = 0x7050c9e0f4ca769c69bd3a8ef740bc37934f8e2c036e5a723fd8ee048ed3f8c3;


function _setImplementation(address newImplementation) public {
   bytes32 slot = IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT;

   assembly {
     sstore(slot, newImplementation)
   }
}

function _implementation() public view returns (address impl) {
   bytes32 slot = IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT;
   assembly {
     impl := sload(slot)
   }
}

function getSlot() public view returns(bytes32) {
    return IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT;
}
}
```

Then created tests to see the results, and see what is modified etc...

```
const Base = artifacts.require("Base")

contract('Base', function(account) {

beforeEach(async function () {
    this.base = await Base.new();
})
describe('...', function () {
    describe('...', function () {
        it('check slot', async function () {
            console.log(await this.base.getSlot());
        })

        it('check slot', async function () {
            console.log(await this.base._implementation());
        })

        it('change slot', async function () {
            console.log(account[0]);
            await this.base._setImplementation(account[0]);
        })

        it('check slot', async function () {
            console.log(await this.base.getSlot());
        })

        it('check slot', async function () {
            console.log(await this.base._implementation());
        })

    })
})
})
```

Which gives the result:

```
0x7050c9e0f4ca769c69bd3a8ef740bc37934f8e2c036e5a723fd8ee048ed3f8c3
    ✓ check slot
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    ✓ check slot
0x627306090abaB3A6e1400e9345bC60c78a8BEf57
    ✓ change slot (69ms)
0x7050c9e0f4ca769c69bd3a8ef740bc37934f8e2c036e5a723fd8ee048ed3f8c3
    ✓ check slot
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    ✓ check slot
```

Why does the slot variable not change, and if that is not meant to change, why does ADMIN_SLOT not change either?

Comment: What made you think that initializing the local (non-state) variable `slot` with the value of the constant `IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT`, and then writing a different value into `slot` (whether you do it in assembly or not), would change the value of the constant `IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT`??? The variable `slot` **does not reference** the variable `IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT` as a result of `slot = IMPLEMENTATION_SLOT`! And in any case, did you actually expect to be able to change the value of a constant in the contract? Why o you think it's called "constant"?

Answer (score 1):

You are deploying a new instance before every test so any changes will be ignored in following tests

```
beforeEach(async function () {
    this.base = await Base.new();
})
```

Comment: Thanks :) 

Out of curiosity, how are we able to modify/retrieve the slot variable if it hasn't been declared out width of the functions scope?
Random thought: Does sstore declare, and also store this in a global sense of the contract?

Comment: As stated by goodvibration you cannot access the local variables from outside the function scope where they were declared. The function `sstore` modifies the contract storage where global variables are stored, but it does not declare a new variable.